# How to close file created with cat in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, cat

I am using the Windows PowerShell and I create a file with

```
cat > test
```

Once I typed that in, I can type in content for the file.
However, how do I close the file/terminate the content writing for the file `test`? On Unix based systems, this would be `ctrl + D`, but that does not seem to work for the PowerShell on Windows...

Comment: In Windows PowerShell, `cat` is an alias for `Get-Content` (closer to [`type`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPE_(DOS_command)) than `cat`). You can't use it to read text from stdin like you might in a unix shell

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen How would I create a document with some text content then? Like `cat > file` on UNIX like systems?

Comment: I usually write multi-line text in the prompt in a [here-string literal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) and pipe that to `Set-Content`. Shift+Enter for linebreaks without execution

Comment: Keep in mind that pipe in PowerShell is | not >.  So "create a string between quotes (or use the here-string mentioned by Mathias for multiline) and then pipe to" | Set-Content

Comment: @DarkMoon, `>` - an effective alias of `Out-File` - is fine, as long as it _follows_ the string (though it's worth noting that in Windows PowerShell `OutFile` and `Set-Content` use different character encodings by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flesh out [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) comment on the question:

In *Windows PowerShell*, `cat` is an alias for the *loosely* equivalent [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet; however, `Get-Content` only operates on *files*.

You can use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) for interactively typing content to be saved to a file (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line, as usual):

```sh
Set-Content test @'
type
your
lines
here
'@    # Type this to finish and save - must be at the *very start* of the line.
```

<sup>If you want to reference *variables and expressions* in the lines you type, use the *expandable* (interpolating) here-string variant, which uses `"` instead of `'`.</sup>

Note:

- Interactively, you'll see the second and all subsequent lines prefixed with `>>` , which is PowerShell's way of signaling that the command being typed isn't complete yet.
- [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) is used to save to a file (and is generally preferable for saving *text* to files); the caveat in *Windows PowerShell* is that it uses the system's active *ANSI* code page to create the file (whereas [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now commendably *consistently* defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8); use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

  - PowerShell supports `>` (and `>>`) too, which delegates to the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet, and in Windows PowerShell therefore creates "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files.
  - While syntactically convenient in general, if you were to use `>` in the case at hand, you would have to - awkwardly - type `> test` *after* the closing `'@` delimiter of the here-string, because - unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` - `>` cannot *start* a command.

Comment: I didn't know that about Out-File vs. Set-Content; I'm going to have to switch now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Get-Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-7.1)

1. Copy the text you want to save to a file.
2. `Get-Clipboard > test`